# How can I read the value of a Firebase database dictionnary created using .childByAutoId() in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dictionary of dictionary of Strings stored in a Firebase database. It can be seen below.

[image: My dictionary]

As you can see, each entry is created using `.childByAutoId()` and contains two variables: `text` and `tag`.
I wish to be able to go through all of the entries, and compare the value of `text` with a variable saved locally in my app. I have tried many ways, but cannot find any solution that works. How should I proceed?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Show what you are trying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to observe database at specific reference and then convert a snapshot that will be send to you. The snapshot represents a fragment of your database at given path

```
        let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
        dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            for message in snapshot.children{
                let msg = (message as! DataSnapshot).value //message as snapshot
                //now you need to cast it to your structure([String:String])
                let projectObj = Message(snapshotChild: msg as! [String:String])
               //and do your comparison
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am having an error with `Message(snapshotChild: msg as! [String:String])`, as the `Message()` method is not recognised by Xcode ('Use of unresolved identifier 'Message').

Comment: of course, Message is just a wrapper class that you can write for your case in order to make the code cleaner. print(msg) and see what you have got in the console